# Jquery Tabs MVC 4 - Redirect to to tab from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-tabs

I have the following code where 'SelectedTabToFind' is set in the controller. This is used for validation, so that the correct tab is displayed.

```
$("#tabs").tabs(
{
active: $("#SelectedTabToFind").val(),
cache: false
});

<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1" title="View">View</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2" title="Update">Update</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3" title="Validate">Validate</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4" title="Notes">Notes</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
     @Html.Partial("View",Model)
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
     @Html.Partial("Update",Model)
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
     @Html.Partial("Validate",Model.ValidateModel)
</div>
<div id="tabs-4">
    @Html.Partial("Notes", Model)
</div>
```

View Tab - Displays Information

Update Tab - Can update information on tab

Validate Tab - Can update information on tab

Notes Tab - Displays a list of information with separate page outwith tabs to add/update a note

The validation works and displays correctly for Update and Validate tabs. The redirect does not work when I add/update a note as it uses a separate page outwith the tabs.

I have used the following code before to redirect to a tab

```
return Redirect(Url.Action("View", new { id = note.Id }) + "#tabs-4");
```

and this does not work with the above code

If I comment out 'active' it works correctly

```
$("#tabs").tabs(
    {
    //active: $("#SelectedTabToFind").val(),
    cache: false
    });
```

How do I redirect to the correct tab but keep active option for validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [JQuery UI tabs: How do I navigate directly to a tab from another page?](http://JQuery%20UI%20tabs:%20How%20do%20I%20navigate%20directly%20to%20a%20tab%20from%20another%20page?)

The correct tab is displayed when validating a form and the redirect from another page works as well.

View Page

```
if (document.location.hash != '')
        {
           var tabSelect = document.location.hash.substr(1, document.location.hash.length);
            //Used to return to tab using return Redirect(Url.Action("View", new { id = note.Id }) + "#4");
           $("#tabs").tabs(
           {
               active: tabSelect,
               cache: false
           });
        }
        else
        {
            $("#tabs").tabs(
            {
                //Used to return to tab using return ViewModel.SelectedTab = 2;
                active: $("#SelectedTabToFind").val(),
                cache: false
            });
        }
```

Used for note section in controller

```
return Redirect(Url.Action("View", new { id = note.Id}) + "#4");
```

Used for Update and Validate section in controller

```
ViewModel.SelectedTab = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you redirectto a tab, that tab becomes automatically active. You cannot do something and its contrary!

From [jquery tabs doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active)

> active 
> Type: Boolean or Integer
> Default: 0
> Which panel is currently open.
> Multiple types supported:

Boolean: Setting active to false will collapse all panels. This requires the collapsible option to be true.
    Integer: The zero-based index of the panel that is active (open). A negative value selects panels going backward from the last panel.

Comment: thanks, so how do I return the correct tab for validation if I remove active: $("#SelectedTabToFind").val(), the first tab is always returned when I would like the second tab to display with validation message?

Comment: @Ros is there a difference between `redirecting to a tab` and `setting a tab as active`? I think no! So do you wan to expand two tabs at the same time?

Comment: I have 4 tabs, two of the tabs allow you to edit information. If the form is not valid then I want to display the correct tab with the error message. This works using the above code. As I set the active value in the controller.